# Confirm HDD/SSD bottleneck

Tags: video, ssd, performance, rendering

I have pretty beast of a PC at work and I often use it for editing and post production mainly in in After Effects and Premiere. During renders in both Premiere and AFX (or media encoder, mixed projects etc) I see weird behaviour. Only about 35-50% of CPU capacity is usually utilised. Typically I see 50% load at 1st core, and about 35% with the rest.

I do have SSD, Samsung 850 EVO 500Gb, but I render from and to that drive and all my scrap/cache is on that same drive as well. my guess would be that my drive is bottlenecking my CPU, but I would like to confirm before I put out request for some monster SSD(s). Mainly I'd like to eliminate the possibility, that this is just Adobe software acting out as it often does.

So my question is, how would I go about that? Is there a benchmarking tool maybe? What variables should I keep eye on during render? Do I check disc active time or transfer rate? Is it possible the SSD is my bottleneck even if it's not going 100% during render?

If that is any help, my specs are:

- Intel i7-5930K set to run max 4 GHz
- 32 GB RAM
- Samsung 850 EVO, 500 GB
- GeForce 980Ti vanilla
- 1000W PSU
- Asus X99-PRO Mobo

Just to be clear, I am 100% sure CPU is not overheating.

Comment: The old adage was don't have project, render or scratch on the same drive; but I have no hard data to back that up, or if indeed that would be the same issue these days as back in the HD days..

Comment: How big is the total size of a project with all files and dependencies?

Comment: All together it has some 175 GB including some external assets.